# complex limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{z^{2}-1}{z^{2}+1}$ exists?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have a question about this problem, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Calculate the following limit:
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{z^{2}-1}{z^{2}+1}$$

my steps:

I tried factoring the denominator and divisor but I can't eliminate the uncertainty so I think that maybe this limit doesn't exist but I'm not sure about it

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{z^{2}-1}{z^{2}+1} = \lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{(z+1)(z-1)}{(z+i)(z-i)}$$

Comment: there is no uncertainity here, you have that $\lim_{z\to i}\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}=i \lim_{z\to i}\frac1{z-i}$ so... (also: you can't use L'Hôpital in other domains than $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: I see :0 ,  but is still divided by z-i so when z tends to i there is no indeterminacy yet ?

Comment: @Masacroso a little known fact is that L'Hopital does indeed apply in $\Bbb{R}^n$ in the least restrictive sense for non isolated singularities. Which this problem is not an example of but it is useful to know.

Comment: $z^{2}-1=[\frac{z^{2}-1}{z^{2}+1}] [z^{2}+1]$. What happens if the ratio has  a limit? $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $z=x+i$ and work around $x=0$
$$\frac{z^{2}-1}{z^{2}+1}=\frac{-2 +2ix+x^2} {x(2i+x) }$$

Comment: Oh i see, then the limit diverges thanks :3